# github does not display commit diff, too large

Tags: github

Instead of the commit diff -- concerning one of my commits -- github just tells me:

```
Sorry, this diff is taking too long to generate.
It may be too large to display on GitHub.
```

If I append `.patch` to the end of the URL, I get the following message:

```
error: too big or took too long to generate
```

I admit that the diff size is 3.6 millon lines (74MB) -- verified at command line using `git diff`.

But if I understand well https://github.blog/2016-12-06-how-we-made-diff-pages-3x-faster tells us (towards the end of the post) that:

```
Overall, the effective limits we enforce for the entire diff became:

    Up to 3,000 files.
    Up to 60,000,000 lines (not loaded automatically).
    Up to 3GB of diff text (also not loaded automatically).
```

which is quite acceptable and far more than I need.

Any idea how can I get this commit diff on github?

Comment: I store output files on github as well, for testing purposes. Output files cause the commit diff becoming that large. One workaround could be: 1) commit _just the code_ and then 2) commit the output files separately. In this case I could see at least the commit diff of the _code_ which is more important in most of the cases, I guess.

Comment: Sorry for not sharing the link to this commit, it is in a private repo.

Comment: *diff size is 3.6 millon lines (74MB)* - Is this a single file diff or multiple files?

Comment: There are 4 scripts + a Makefile, all below 3K. Additionally, there 11 output files, ranging from 700K to 8M in size. I would be happy to see the diff only for the scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that [blog post](https://github.blog/2016-12-06-how-we-made-diff-pages-3x-faster/) is of *December 6, 2016*, so might be outdated.

As of now, according to [GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/limits-for-viewing-content-and-diffs-in-a-repository#diff-limits) the diff limits are

> Because diffs can become very large, we impose these limits on diffs
>   for commits, pull requests, and compare views:
>
> - No single file's diff may exceed 20,000 lines that you can load or 1
>     MB of raw diff data. Four hundred lines and 20 KB are automatically
>     loaded for a single file.
> - The maximum number of files in a single diff
>     is limited to 3,000.
> - The maximum number of renderable files (such as
>     images, PDFs, and GeoJSON files) in a single diff is limited to 25.
>
> Some portions of a limited diff may be displayed, but anything
>   exceeding the limit is not shown.

So if your diff numbers don't fall below the specified limits, **I don't think you can view that on GitHub.com**

Answer (score 1):

If we insist on using github, **a very uncomfortable *partial* solution** can be:

1. Go to the specific commit in commits listing.
2. Copy the commit message.
3. Press `<>` to browse the repo at this point in history.
4. Choose a file whose diff you want to see. (It is possible only one-by-one...)
5. Switch to `Blame` mode at top right.
6. Search for the commit message (Ctrl-F + Ctrl-V).

That's it.

This shows only *which parts of the file was changed* not a genuine commit diff. This method works only for small files.